# Do I need to import the AppDelegate_Phone.h file?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, import, dependencies

Do I need to import the AppDelegate_Phone.h file (which in turn imports AppDelegate_Shared.h)?

I am trying to use Core Data. The `AppDelegate_Shared.h` already has it set up. If I want to read information into a UITableView from Core Data, must I import my delegate file explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think so, but I also don't see a down side to doing it anyway.